# Can you have multiple rest states for an armature?

Tags: rigging, armature

I want to make a character that wears heels, so that would naturally change her height and the way her feet bones are placed.

I could just duplicate the armature with the new default position, but I was wondering if there is another option for having several rest states?

Comment: As far as I know there is only one default rest position. But you could add several poses to a pose library, so if you apply one of those poses it's like resetting the rig to that pose, too.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Yes, I guess that would work. Hadn't thought of it because I had in my mind also exporting it to unity or something but I guess I could just apply the pose for the version I'd export.

Comment: Okay, maybe exporting it to Unity you'll have to make it different. Most of the time I'm doing all my 3D stuff in Blender so that's no problem.